# MFMailComposeVC

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am using the `MFMailComposeViewController` to let user send email within my app.
after create and show this system mail composer with `presentModalViewController`: i waited for the delegate call :

```
- (void) mailComposeController: (MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult: (MFMailComposeResult)result error: (NSError *)error
```

in this delegate (which is also the only delegate i can find) method i close the mailComposerView.

Every thing works fine except when after user input some content but  choose 'cancel' instead of 'send', there will be an system action sheet  with option 'Save', 'Delete' and 'Cancel'. if user choose 'Save', which  means save the mail draft, there will be a quite long time interval  before the delegate method is called. thus, my UI looks like was  hanging.

Another thing i obsereved is that if you put your app in backgorud during this hang-out the app get crashed on resume due to watchdog.(Not resumed in time)
This crash is also in the iOS native photo app if follow same steps.
Anyone have any idea how can i avoid this? or maybe any other solution  that i can send email in app rather then using  `MFMailComposeViewController`?

Answer (score 1):

I also had some issues with the `MFMailComposeViewController` and because it is only used for feedback I finally decided to send the user of to the Mail app by using

```
NSString *recipientsAndSubject = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"mailto:%@?subject=%@", recipient, subject];
NSString *email = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&body=%@", recipientsAndSubject, body];
email = [email stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:email]];
```

My issue was, that right after using the `MFMailComposeViewController`, some scrolling within my VC became sluggish. This only happened if you clicked anything in the MFMailComposeVC. If you just left it deleting the draft, scrolling was fine...

Comment: Thanks this can be great alternative to the my issue.